# I use Windows auth for our internal websites. Why can some users log in and others not? ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

I use IIS 7.5 on Win 2008 R2

I have a pretty simple site setup so that the billing department here at my workplace can get in and print invoices for various clients.  The site uses Windows Authentication, and worked up until this morning, when one of the sales people tried to log in and print some invoices.  It gave them a 401 error.  When I tried to log in I could not replicate the issue with my username, but I could with his.

Here's the web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="MYCOMPANY\billing_SOMECOMPANY"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Now, all the users are in the group that we'll call "billing_SOMECOMPANY", so they should be able to log in right?  If not, what could be stopping me?

Comment: Is his user suspended/inactive?

Comment: No, it's been several users, actually everyone in the billing group can't get to it, but everyone in the developer group (me and one other guy) can.